# Parent div is overflow auto. Child div is out of parent. How to show child div?

Tags: html, css

Parent and child divs are both absolute positioned. Parent div hides its child when it is auto-overflowed. Is there any way to show child in this situation?

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(39, 172, 255);
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an odd request, you have applied overflow-y, WHY? Why position the child outside the visible area in the first place if you want to see it?

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is and maybe provide us with a code snippet?

Comment: The simplest option is to remove `position:absolute` from the parent. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wveWGwL

Comment: Without position: absolute, I cannot set child position relative to its parent.

Comment: @Nikita You can set `position: relative` on the parent to set child position relative to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

As @Paulie_D mentioned you could remove the `position: absolute;` from the parent div. But then the position of the inner div wont be positioned relative to the parent.

To achieve this, you have to give the parent the position `relative`. Also remove `overflow-y: auto;` so both divs will always be visible.